# Grails environment not set in tomcat. application.yml file does not use custom environment settings

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat7

I have a grails app that I run locally and build using `grails -Dgrails.env=dev run-app`. The following is true in both my development and qa tomcat instance servers.

```
grailsApplication.config.get('grails.env') == 'dev'
```

So then grails finds the correct configuration from `application.yml` through the `grailsApplication.config` property. (see first Update below for description).

When our build server constructs the `war` file using `grails -Dgrails.env=dev war` I receive the correct war with a build.info in META-INF that has the correct environment variable set to `dev`. however, calling

```
grailsApplication.config.get('grails.env') == '{"initializing":"true"}'
```

According to `grails.util.Environment` class:

```
/**
 * Whether Grails is in the middle of bootstrapping or not
 */
public static final String INITIALIZING = "grails.env.initializing";
```

I have tried to set the variable using the shorter `grails <env> war` syntax as well as placing it in the `GRAILS_OPTS` variable to no avail. However I believe as long as it ends up in the `META-INF/grails.build.info` file it should have theoretically worked anyway (see `grails.util.Environment.resolveCurrentEnvironment()` method).

The difference here is tomcat as far as I can tell, but I couldn't tell you why it freezes at initialization. I don't have any other non-trivial way that I can set the environment variable apart from this method which AFAIK is the standard way of doing so.

Any ideas?

P.S. I am accessing this property through a temporary Controller that injects the `grailsApplication` into it and returns whatever mapping it finds in `grailsApplication.config` for the key you provide it.

### UPDATE:

I managed to find the correct environment using `Environment.current.name`, so I currently have a work around if need be, however the custom properties that exist in my `application.yml` are still not being picked up.

e.g.

```
# application.yml
app.my-prop: false

  environments:
    dev:
      app:
        my-prop: true
```

grailsApplication.config.getProperty('app.my-prop', boolean, false) returns `true` in my local when i run it with `grails -Dgrails.env=dev run-app` but `false` on the server with the `grails -Dgrails.env=dev war` deployable.

Answer (score 0):

**Invoke `Environment.getCurrent()` before resolving configuration.**

It works now. I'm not 100% sure why, but I have a theory:

I wanted to constrict the controller only to the development environment and I remembered one of my colleagues used a method `GrailsUtil.isDevelopmentEnv()` to check that, so as a precaution I added an `if` statement that checks the environment before rendering the configuration value response.

```
if (GrailsUtil.isDevelopmentEnv() || System.getProperty(Environment.KEY) == 'dev') { 
  ...
}
```

However once I added the check, the custom `application.yml` property resolved correctly!

My current theory is that the `Environment.getCurrent()` method that `GrailsUtil.isDevelopmentEnv()` inspects the System property and then if that isn't found, inspects the META-INF/grails.build.info file and caches the result. maybe the problem is that the environment setting is resolved this way when `grailsApplication.config.getProperty()` is invoked but it isn't initialized through this method.

I'm using grails version 3.1.16 and this may be fixed in later versions, but for now I'm happy with this solution.

Comment: Can you please mention where this is to be invoked? I tried it at the beginning of the `main` method in Application.groovy as well as at the beginning of the `init` function in Bootstrap.groovy, but none of these is being reached before my stacktrace is thrown. Thanks!